# AJAX .done() returning undefined with $.each() on JSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I cant access the JSON results from an $.ajax() request. I'm getting a result from the api once i select a car model, but I can't access the JSON response to get the information I need to propogate a new drop down list.

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col">   
        <label>Make</label>
        <select class="custom-select" id="vMake">
        <option selected="" disabled="">Choose Make</option>
        <?php
            require "config.php"; 
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_cars";
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->execute();
            $cars = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach ($cars as $cars) {
                echo "<option id='".$cars['make']."' value='".$cars['make']."'>".$cars['make']."</option>";
            }
        ?>
        </select>   
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Model</label>
        <select class="custom-select col" id="vModel">
            
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#vMake').on('change', function(){
        var make = $(this).val();
        var url = "https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/GetModelsForMake/" + make + "?format=json";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",                    
        }).done(function(data){
           
           
           $('#vModel').empty();
           
           $.each(data, function(i, e){
               
               
                var model = data[i].Model_Name;
                $('#vModel').append('<option value="' + model +'">'+ model + '</option>'); 
            });
                
           
        });
    });
})
```

My console result

```
{"Count":163,"Message":"Response returned successfully","SearchCriteria":"Make:Ford","Results":[{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":1778,"Model_Name":"Crown Victoria"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":1779,"Model_Name":"Focus"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":1780,"Model_Name":"Fusion"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":1781,"Model_Name":"Mustang"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":1782,"Model_Name":"Taurus"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":1796,"Model_Name":"E-150"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":1797,"Model_Name":"Edge"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":1798,"Model_Name":"Escape"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":1799,"Model_Name":"Expedition"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":1800,"Model_Name":"Explorer"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":1801,"Model_Name":"F-150"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":1802,"Model_Name":"Flex"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":1803,"Model_Name":"Ranger"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":1804,"Model_Name":"Explorer Sport Trac"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":1805,"Model_Name":"F-250"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":1806,"Model_Name":"F-350"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":1807,"Model_Name":"F-450"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":1808,"Model_Name":"F-550"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":1809,"Model_Name":"F-650"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":1810,"Model_Name":"F-750"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":1811,"Model_Name":"Transit Connect"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":1817,"Model_Name":"E-250"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":1818,"Model_Name":"E-350"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":1819,"Model_Name":"E-450"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":1820,"Model_Name":"Expedition MAX"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":2345,"Model_Name":"Thunderbird"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":2346,"Model_Name":"GT"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":2347,"Model_Name":"Five Hundred"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":2370,"Model_Name":"Excursion"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":2379,"Model_Name":"Freestyle"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":2384,"Model_Name":"Freestar"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":2737,"Model_Name":"Motorhome Chassis"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":3160,"Model_Name":"Taurus X"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":3267,"Model_Name":"Fiesta"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":3410,"Model_Name":"Commercial Chassis"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":3462,"Model_Name":"C-max"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":3608,"Model_Name":"Transit"},{"Make_ID":1237,"Make_Name":"Affordable Aluminum","Model_ID":4563,"Model_Name":"Affordable Aluminum"},{"Make_ID":1298,"Make_Name":"Eagle Ford Tanks & Trailers LLC","Model_ID":4645,"Model_Name":"Eagle Ford Tanks & Trailers LLC "},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":5181,"Model_Name":"Escort"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":5182,"Model_Name":"ZX2"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":5264,"Model_Name":"Windstar"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":5342,"Model_Name":"E-550"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":5346,"Model_Name":"B-750"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":5361,"Model_Name":"F-800"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":5868,"Model_Name":"Explorer Sport"},{"Make_ID":2431,"Make_Name":"Milford Welding & Manufacturing","Model_ID":6243,"Model_Name":"Milford Welding & Manufacturing Inc."},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":6703,"Model_Name":"Aspire"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":6730,"Model_Name":"Probe"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":6731,"Model_Name":"Contour"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":6825,"Model_Name":"Bronco"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":6857,"Model_Name":"Aerostar"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":7331,"Model_Name":"F-150 Heritage"},{"Make_ID":3609,"Make_Name":"Waterford Tank and Fabrication","Model_ID":7985,"Model_Name":"Waterford Tank and Fabrication, LTD"},{"Make_ID":4265,"Make_Name":"Milford Pipe & Supply","Model_ID":9047,"Model_Name":"Milford Pipe & Supply"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9213,"Model_Name":"L8501"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9214,"Model_Name":"LT8501"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9215,"Model_Name":"L9501"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9216,"Model_Name":"LT9501"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9217,"Model_Name":"L8511"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9218,"Model_Name":"LT8511"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9219,"Model_Name":"L9511"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9220,"Model_Name":"LT9511"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9221,"Model_Name":"L8513"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9222,"Model_Name":"LT8513"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9223,"Model_Name":"L9513"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9224,"Model_Name":"LT9513"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9225,"Model_Name":"L9522"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9226,"Model_Name":"LT9522"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9227,"Model_Name":"A8513"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9228,"Model_Name":"AT8513"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9229,"Model_Name":"A9513"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9230,"Model_Name":"AT9513"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9231,"Model_Name":"A9522"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9232,"Model_Name":"AT9522"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9268,"Model_Name":"B800"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9270,"Model_Name":"F-Super Duty"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9272,"Model_Name":"F-700"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9282,"Model_Name":"P700"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9283,"Model_Name":"P800"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9284,"Model_Name":"FT900"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9285,"Model_Name":"L8000"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9286,"Model_Name":"L9000"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9287,"Model_Name":"LL9000"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9288,"Model_Name":"LLA9000"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9289,"Model_Name":"LLS9000"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9290,"Model_Name":"LS8000"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9291,"Model_Name":"LS9000"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9292,"Model_Name":"LT8000"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9293,"Model_Name":"LT9000"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9294,"Model_Name":"LTS8000"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9295,"Model_Name":"LTS9000"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9296,"Model_Name":"LTL9000"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9297,"Model_Name":"LTLA9000"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9298,"Model_Name":"LTLS9000"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9299,"Model_Name":"LA8000"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9300,"Model_Name":"LA9000"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9301,"Model_Name":"LTA9000"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9302,"Model_Name":"LN7000"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9303,"Model_Name":"LN8000"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9304,"Model_Name":"LN9000"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9305,"Model_Name":"LNT8000"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9306,"Model_Name":"LNT9000"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9307,"Model_Name":"CF8000"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9308,"Model_Name":"CFT8000"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":9312,"Model_Name":"CF7000"},{"Make_ID":4533,"Make_Name":"Fords Trailer Sales","Model_ID":9637,"Model_Name":"Fords Trailer Sales"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":10378,"Model_Name":"Festiva"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":11942,"Model_Name":"Low Cab Forward"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":13958,"Model_Name":"Tempo"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":13977,"Model_Name":"B600"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":13978,"Model_Name":"B700"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":13979,"Model_Name":"F-600"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":13980,"Model_Name":"Recreational Vehicle"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":13981,"Model_Name":"F-590"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":13983,"Model_Name":"P600"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":14148,"Model_Name":"CL9000"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":14149,"Model_Name":"CLT9000"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":14150,"Model_Name":"Bronco II"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":14152,"Model_Name":"FT800"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":14153,"Model_Name":"CT8000"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":14154,"Model_Name":"C800"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":14155,"Model_Name":"C8000"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":14196,"Model_Name":"Laser"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":14199,"Model_Name":"LTD"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":14614,"Model_Name":"Fairmont"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":14618,"Model_Name":"Granada"},{"Make_ID":5697,"Make_Name":"ASHFORD MFG ","Model_ID":14916,"Model_Name":"Travel Park "},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":14930,"Model_Name":"'34 "},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":15160,"Model_Name":"CF6000"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":15194,"Model_Name":"B7000"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":15195,"Model_Name":"C7000"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":15197,"Model_Name":"F7000"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":15198,"Model_Name":"F8000"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":15203,"Model_Name":"FT8000"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":15204,"Model_Name":"Courier"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":15205,"Model_Name":"B6000"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":15206,"Model_Name":"C600"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":15208,"Model_Name":"C700"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":15209,"Model_Name":"F6000"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":15223,"Model_Name":"LN600"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":15225,"Model_Name":"LN700"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":15251,"Model_Name":"L800"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":15252,"Model_Name":"LT800"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":15254,"Model_Name":"LN800"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":15255,"Model_Name":"LNT800"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":15273,"Model_Name":"E-100"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":15280,"Model_Name":"F-100"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":15291,"Model_Name":"CT800"},{"Make_ID":6163,"Make_Name":"Swinford Mfg","Model_ID":16298,"Model_Name":"Swinford Mfg"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":17774,"Model_Name":"Ecosport"},{"Make_ID":6579,"Make_Name":"CRANFORD RADIATOR INC.","Model_ID":17910,"Model_Name":"CRANFORD RADIATOR INC."},{"Make_ID":6674,"Make_Name":"BRADFORD BUILT","Model_ID":18064,"Model_Name":"BRADFORD BUILT"},{"Make_ID":6792,"Make_Name":"Stanford Customs","Model_ID":18235,"Model_Name":"Malibu Sedan"},{"Make_ID":6792,"Make_Name":"Stanford Customs","Model_ID":18236,"Model_Name":"Cordova Sedan"},{"Make_ID":6792,"Make_Name":"Stanford Customs","Model_ID":18237,"Model_Name":"Classic Sedan"},{"Make_ID":8578,"Make_Name":"Bradford #1","Model_ID":22551,"Model_Name":"Bradford #1"},{"Make_ID":8948,"Make_Name":"Stafford's Trailers","Model_ID":23075,"Model_Name":"Stafford's Trailers"},{"Make_ID":9569,"Make_Name":"Medford Steel","Model_ID":23878,"Model_Name":"Medford Steel"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":25742,"Model_Name":"Expedition EL"},{"Make_ID":10240,"Make_Name":"Affordable Trailers","Model_ID":26910,"Model_Name":"Affordable Trailers"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":27411,"Model_Name":"Bronco Sport"},{"Make_ID":460,"Make_Name":"Ford","Model_ID":27440,"Model_Name":"Mustang Mach-E"}]}
```

I'm trying to get the model name of the result. But as shown on image below I get undefined in my second dropdown. How can I get the information I need?

[image: Result of my code]

Comment: `e` will also already be your `data[i]`.  There's no need to explicitly type that out.  Use the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, remove this:

```
var data;
```

You already have a variable called `data` in that function, so if this line is doing anything it's overwriting that variable and making the whole thing `undefined`.  (And if it's not doing that, it's still entirely superfluous and will serve to only confuse you.)

Aside from that, from your JSON it looks like what you want to loop over isn't `data`, but `data.Results`:

```
$.each(data.Results, function(i, e){
  //...
});
```

Comment: I'm getting the 133 results in my dropdown, but still getting undefined. Is their something not working in my ``` $('#vModel').append('<option value="' + model +'">'+ model + '</option>');```

Comment: @gigentor: You've changed the code in your question.  Why?  Did you make that change to your code?  Because `data.Results.Model_Name` is indeed undefined.  `data.Results` is an array.  You're looping over that array.  (Per a comment on the question you can simplify and just use the variable `e` in your `forEach` callback, so you'd want `e.Model_Name`.)

Comment: Yes I made the change to the code. Using the e.Model_Name did the trick. Thanks for your help. I'm new at this.

Comment: @gigentor: I've rolled back your change in the question, since it invalidated the answer by changing the problem.  There's no need to update your question with the correct code, the answer serves that purpose.  It's important to keep the problem evident in the question so future readers can understand if they're having the same problem.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks again.